# Javascript namespacing and private modules

Tags: javascript, namespaces, private

This is a JS newbie questions, I am working with a parent namespace *Base* and I include all my code within this namespace.

file model.js

```
 Base = {}

 Base.Observer =  {
   method1 : function(){//...},
   method2 : function(){//...}
 };

 Base.Bot = function(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.somefunc = function(){};
 }
```

file presenter.js

```
Base.Presenter = {

}
```

file helper.js

```
Base.Helper = { };
```

Now my problem is I would like to keep this module private. Without allowing any user access through any browser tools like firebug. So I could only think of wrapping them within a self executing anonymous function and making *Base* into a local variable which would lead to the *presenter.js* and *helper.js* not being able to access the *Base* namespace.

I would like to keep the files separate as it helps in keeping code organizated but I can't seem to figure what is the correct way to do this. Would appreciate any help on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I could only think of wrapping them within a self executing anonymous function and making Base into a local variable

That is the usual approach

> which would lead to the presenter.js and helper.js not being able to access the Base namespace.

The function should `return Base;` which you then assign to a global.

See [the module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth)